# How to use MySQL FORMAT with CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, formatting

I cant figure out why when I try to use FORMAT function to limit number of decimal places in the results of MySQL query it doesn't work. Here is how my code looks like:

```
...some other options to join tables with some conditions....

$options['fields'] = array(
    'MetricSim.sim_id',
    'MetricSim.metric_id',
    'FORMAT(MetricSim.value,3) AS value'
);
$metrics_sims = $this->Sim->find('all', $options);
```

If I don't use the `FORMAT` function I get all of the results as expected. But when I try to use it I just don't get `value` field in my results (the rest of the fields are in place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use FORMAT in your query? You can use a Helper to format your data in your view.

For example, in your controller class you add:

```
var $helpers = array('Number');
```

and in your view, you can format the value like:

```
$number->format($metric_sims['MetricSim']['value']);
```

(See [NumberHelper](http://api.cakephp.org/class/number-helper) class)

Comment: Ended up formatting outside the query. Accepting your answer since it pushed me in the right direction. Thanks!